# Split CakePHP's controller into several files

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have CakePHP controller with lot's of code in it... What is best practice to split controllers into several files?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if in controller you have to many methods to get data from db consider putting methods inside model. That might help

Comment: i would like to put them into several files. it there a solution for that?

Comment: Group them by functionality and it will work (more or less)

Answer (score 1):

You have to separate your logic:

- User different controllers for tasks related to different models (e.g. products_controller.php, carts_controller.php).
- Separate the business logic into the model (fat model approach).
- Separate re-used controller logic in components.
- Make your code DRY (Don't repeat yourself)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Suppose all of your suggestions have been done and you still have one humongous PHP file with 10,000 lines of code and 25 distinct public and private functions? What is the best way to split that Controller (or fat Model) into multiple, easier to manage, pieces? For example, in a VIew, I would split off pieces into Elements.

Comment: This was actually covered with the recommendation to separate re-used controller logic in components. I could have been more elaborate but this basically covers it.

Comment: I guess the components is the best way to go. From the documentation, it appears designed for sharing code between different controllers, but I suppose there's nothing preventing them from being exclusive to one, just to have more modularization.

Comment: No offense but I don't really see how this will help to make the code more organized by just moving code that is not used anywhere else into a component. Like that, we "hide" complexity but we not really get rid of it.

Comment: It is well known that the human mind is incapable (or has difficulty) understanding any written information that is larger than a page or two of text. Anything you can do to break down your project into smaller, more manageable, easier to understand pieces is good for maintenance. Whether or not any particular piece of code would benefit from being so broken apart is a judgement call, and the more experience you have, the better you'll do. But I'd say, as a general rule of thumb, if your code is more than 10 or 20 thousand lines of code, it's a good candidate for break-up.

Comment: And besides that, what I've very often found is, you might as well break your code into pieces **as if** those pieces were going to be used elsewhere, because sooner or later, as development progresses, you're likely to find a use for those pieces. Then it's easier to modularize if it's already modular. Design for the future, it'll be here sooner than you think!